# How to install wps office via terminal?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, wps-office

It's pretty complicated and sometimes the system freezes when I try to download and install wps office. I think it is much more convenient to use the terminal. But I never used installed WPS Office from the command line. That would be great if I could update it using software manager or terminal. Third party deb files are from separate locations. I specifically want to know about WPS

Comment: Did you try to download the .deb from here: http://wps-community.org/download.html, then install it as per the answer here: [Installation of WPS Office on Ubuntu Software Center cause the system to freeze](http://askubuntu.com/q/399011) ?

Comment: Just type *sudo apt-get install gdebi* in terminal, and then open the wps.deb package with gdebi. It works pretty easy for me.

Comment: @JonasCz You can't download it from there right now - it's down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Comment: rm wps-office.deb does uninstall wps office.. had to re-install it afterwards

Answer (score 24):

OK so...

32-bit (depending on your hardware - check by uname -a):

```
cd && wget -O wps-office.deb http://kdl.cc.ksosoft.com/wps-community/download/a21/wps-office_10.1.0.5672~a21_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i wps-office.deb
sudo apt-get -f install && rm wps-office.deb
wget -O web-office-fonts.deb http://kdl.cc.ksosoft.com/wps-community/download/a15/wps-office-fonts_1.0_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i web-office-fonts.deb
```

For 64-bit:

```
cd && wget -O wps-office.deb http://kdl1.cache.wps.com/ksodl/download/linux/a21//wps-office_10.1.0.5707~a21_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i wps-office.deb
sudo apt-get -f install && rm wps-office.deb
wget -O web-office-fonts.deb http://kdl.cc.ksosoft.com/wps-community/download/fonts/wps-office-fonts_1.0_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i web-office-fonts.deb
```

And that's it.

Edit: As the `wget` links are likely to break at every version change, you can also visit the download page [here](http://wps-community.org/download.html) as noted by [JonasCZ](https://askubuntu.com/users/383125/jonascz) in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783927/how-to-install-wps-office-via-terminal#comment1174753_783927)

Comment: any views on how to update it from terminal?

Answer (score 11):

WPS Office is an office productivity suite, including Writer, Presentation and Spreadsheets. WPS Office is a native snap package in Ubuntu. To install it in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install wps-office  
sudo snap connect wps-office:removable-media
```

wps-office-multilang a multilanguage snap package for WPS Office. It is a slightly larger snap package than wps-office which contains the WPS Office Suite and  support for many languages. In order to install wps-office-multilang type:

```
sudo snap install wps-office-multilang
```

To list the supported languages of wps-office-multilang run `snap info wps-office-multilang`.

The wps-office snap packages will be updated automatically when updates are available. If you didn't already update it from the terminal you will receive a notification from the Software app to install the latest update when it becomes available.