# How to install WPS Office via Command Line

Tags: command-line, package-management, dependencies, wps-office

I'm following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783927/how-to-install-wps-office-via-terminal) guide to install WPS Office but when I run the dpkg command, the following appears in the terminal:

```
(Reading database ... 291111 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack wps-office.deb ...
Unpacking wps-office (10.1.0.5672~a21) over (10.1.0.5672~a21) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wps-office:
 wps-office depends on libpng12-0; however:
  Package libpng12-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package wps-office (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+17.04.20170406-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.8-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wps-office
```

Then, when I run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f && rm wps-office.deb
```

The following is output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  wps-office
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 367 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

I switched to Ubuntu from ChromeOS about a week and a half ago so this is all very new to me and any help you can give would be *greatly* appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, you don't have package `libpng12-0` installed.  Download the correct one for your architecture.

- [For 64-bit](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libpng12-0/download)
- [For 32-bit](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/i386/libpng12-0/download)

Then open terminal and run the command below to install libpng12-0 package

```
sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u2_amd64.deb
```

For 64-bit, or

```
sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_i386.deb
```

For 32-bit

And then run

```
sudo dpkg -i wps-office_10.1.0.5672~a21_amd64.deb
```

To install WPS Office.

Answer (score 1):

install libpng first then install WPS Office.

dpkg is usually good about satisfying dependencies, so libpng might not be available from your current repositories.

you can get it here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libpng12-0