# Cannot Download WPS Office for Linux

Tags: wps-office

It's April 2020 and I am on the WPS Linux page: http://linux.wps.com/. I clicked the big blue Download button but nothing happened. I've been searching how to download it through terminal or other ways but couldn't find one. Can someone help?

[Image WPS Linux Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzxYZ.png)

Comment: You haven't provide OS/release details, the web site does scripts to run, my chosen setup has those scripts blocked until I grant permission to run; you don't have like security setup & operational?  You've provided no release details, no browser or extension setup, and I'd check for a setup that blocks it.

Comment: Oh.. maybe there's a plugin in my browser that blocks it. Sorry I didn't think about that. Anyway there's another post about how to download from terminal. https://askubuntu.com/questions/783927/how-to-install-wps-office-via-terminal

Comment: I was using chrome with plugin **Wappalyzer** which turns out blocking that popup to show. If anyone has [Wappalyzer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wappalyzer/gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg), disable it first then you can see the popup shown by Liso in the answer section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mine does appear, you have to wait a few seconds until the page is fully loaded.

[image]

However as I already fetch the ddl, you can wget it directly.

```
wget http://wdl1.pcfg.cache.wpscdn.com/wpsdl/wpsoffice/download/linux/9505/wps-office_11.1.0.9505.XA_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i wps-office_11.1.0.9505.XA_amd64.deb
```

If you running 16.04 and later (which you should anyway), chances are you have snappy. Luckily [wps](https://snapcraft.io/wps-office) also available in snap.

```
sudo snap install wps-office
```