# WPS office is very slow

Tags: wps-office

I installed wps 2019 office from https://www.wps.com/download on ubuntu 20.04 but it takes more than 20 seconds to start. 
It could start very fast before upgraded to 20.04 (but I forgot the version of wps i was using before upgrade). 
Do you get the same problem?

Comment: +1, I installed same latest wps office deb file, 19.10 is a lot faster, I was very impressive for its performance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install wps office via terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783927/how-to-install-wps-office-via-terminal) This installs the native Ubuntu WPS Office package.

Comment: I uninstalled wps-office/now 11.1.0.9505.XA amd64, and then use snap to install wps-office 10.1.0.6757 from liuyang8, it starts very fast now.