# Official .deb WPS Office very slow in opening file - snap version fixes the problem - Why?

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice, qt, qt5, wps-office

I have installed WPS Office ver. 11.1.0.9719 from [official website](https://linux.wps.com/) and official .deb x86_64 package.

This version of WPS Office is very slow in opening some files.

For example, I have this .docx file that WPS Office takes 15 seconds to open, while LibreOffice Writer opens it in 1/2 seconds.

The solution [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ywSTux_kzQ), which implies changing the theme on which WPS Office runs, unfortunately does not work for me.

I don't even think that the command is correct: if I run WPS Office with `et -style=XXX`, I can put whatever I want in `XXX` and it never throws any error, and I notice no difference whatsoever, nor in terms of UI nor in terms of file opening times (not even with the proposed `-style=motif`).

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232489/wps-office-is-very-slow) does not answer my question as it redirects in installing WPS from snap.

Installing 10.1.0.6757 using `snap` fixes the problem. Why is that?

My system is:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.19.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.74.0
Qt Version: 5.14.2
Kernel Version: 5.8.0-33-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 12 × Intel® Core™ i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
Memory: 15,5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: GeForce GTX 1060/PCIe/SSE2
```

Answer (score 3):

**NEW ANSWER**: It may be due to accessing the internet. Forbidding WPS from accessing the internet makes opening a document significantly faster. The snap version blocks internet access by default, the .deb version does not. See [answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1320083/176654).

**OLD ANSWER**

This was due to missing fonts. If the document is written with fonts that are missing on the system, WPS Office engage in lengthy process of font substitution, and apparently that process is much more lengthy in ver. 11 than in ver. 10.

To fix the problem:

1. Wait patiently until your document is loaded. This make take up to a minute or more
2. Once the document is loaded, go to Menu -> Options

[image: WPS Menu -> Options]

3. Click on "Font Substitution"

[image]

Wait until the new window is loaded. This may take a while (30 sec / 1 min)

4. The "Font Substitution" window should appear. On the left you find the missing fonts, on the right the fonts that have been used as a substitute. Take notice on what fonts you miss. In the following example, we miss only one font, "Tahoma"

[image]

5. Close WPS. Go on the web and download the fonts that you miss. Copy the missing fonts in a directory in fontconfig search path (for instance, `/usr/share/fonts/`)
6. Run `fc-cache -f`
7. Re-open the file. This time WPS Office should open it very rapidly.

   You can check that you miss no other fonts. Repeating 2 and 3 should return you the following window:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, installing `wps` from `snap` will achieve a better speed of startup, but it is still slow (2-3 seconds, right?).

The reason why `wps` is slow in startup is due to conflict between `wps` and `ibus`. I know this is hard to believe, but if you install `fcitx` and set it to the default input method and restart your computer, you will find `wps` (installed from `.deb`, not from `snap`) starts in 1 second. This is tested on my machine.

If you do not want to install `fcitx` immediately but wonder whether it is the fault of `ibus`, you can run `ibus exit` and see whether the startup of `wps` speed up, but I did not do this ever and cannot guarantee the effect.

Comment: No that was not it for me. Still around 30 seconds to open the file with no input method, ibus, or fcitx. But thanks very much for the suggestion and for bringing your experience. I didn't know the different input methods.

Comment: @raffaem Sorry to hear that, good luck to you!

Answer (score 1):

Actually it may be due to internet access.

The [snap version](https://snapcraft.io/wps-2019-snap) of WPS Office blocks it from accessing the internet, and opening a file is very fast.

The [flatpak version](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.wps.Office) doesn't default to block internet connection (see [here](https://github.com/flathub/com.wps.Office/issues/4)), and opening a file is very slow (it takes up to 5/6 minutes to open a presentation).

If I revoke internet access permissions:

`sudo flatpak override com.wps.Office --unshare=network`

the opening of a file is significantly greater sped up (from 6 minutes to 1/2 seconds).

Just to double check, if I concede internet access again:

`sudo flatpak override com.wps.Office --share=network`

Opening of a file is slow again.

Again, this didn't happen with `snap` because it blocks internet access by default.

This looks really strange and suspicious ....

Comment: Well, WPS Office is not free (as in libre). Who knows what it does ?... I personaly stick to LibreOffice.

Comment: @alci I know but LO has not enough compatibility with MSO for my use case unfortunately ....